# Batch file to logoff between specific times

Tags: batch-file, timer

I want to make a batch file to log off after an hour has passed and i want it to reset at noon and midnight (ex. on computer for one hour, Logged off, have to wait until 12 to get back on) I have the timer script (below) but I'm not sure how to create the time check and all of that
-Thanks

```
echo.
echo            You have one Hour...Begin 
TIMEOUT /T 3600 /NOBREAK>NUL
echo.
echo (code here)
echo.
pause >nul
```

Comment: logoff-command: `shutdown -l` see `shutdown /?` for more options

Comment: I know that but i need it to check if hes been on since 12 for the entire hour

Answer (score 0):

Hmm this is interesting lol. Try and use the if command

```
:lol
timeout /t 20 /nobreak >nul
if %time% GTR 12:00:00 (
goto logoff
)
if %time% LSS 12:00:00 (
goto lol
)
:logoff
shutdown -l
```

This won't work 100% correctly, but you get the idea :P
Try using the set command to translate 12:00:00 to the number 12 then use the if command.